# Python regex sub using compile object

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex `<type '_sre.SRE_Pattern'>` and I would like to substitute the matched string with another string. Here is what I have:

```
compiled = re.compile(r'some regex expression')
s = 'some regex expression plus some other stuff'
compiled.sub('substitute', s)
print(s)
```

and `s` should be

```
'substitute plus some other stuff'
```

However, my code is not working and the string is not changing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) is *not* an inplace operation. From the docs:

> *Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping
>   occurrences of pattern in string by the replacement repl.*

Ergo, you must assign the return value back to `a`.

```
...
s = compiled.sub('substitute', s)
print(s)
```

This gives

```
'substitute plus some other stuff'
```

As you'd expect.